# Python matlib text on bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add text to each bar in bar chart because now I have only like 5,10,15 on the bottom.

I am looking for solution to add text for each or just text on the top for each.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar([i for i  in range(1, 24)], [i for i in range(1, 24)])
plt.title('Chart by hours in total')
plt.savefig('out.png')
```

[image: The one I have now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical matplotlib: can be done, but requires some work.

```
def label(rects, texts):
    """Attach a text label on each rect"""
    for rect, txt in zip(rects, texts):
        height = rect.get_height()
        if height != 0:
            plt.text(
                rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2.0,
                height / 2.0,
                txt,
                ha='center',
                va='center',
                fontsize=9,
                rotation='vertical',
            )

b = plt.bar([i for i  in range(1, 24)], [i for i in range(1, 24)])
texts = [f'{k}' for k in range(24)]
label(b, texts)
plt.title('Chart by hours in total')
```

You can adapt the code to your needs. Currently, it inserts vertically oriented text at midpoint of each bar.

[image]